# .NET Click-once installation failure (x86 vs x64?)?

Tags: .net, installation, version, clickonce, x86-64

The IT team is attempting to install a click-once app on a Windows 7 machine. It has successfully installed on Windows 7 before without problem.

But this time we are getting an error:

[image]

This Winforms app is targeted at x86 platform and .NET framework 2.0.

Any ideas??

**Edit:**

I think what is happening is that this Windows 7 machine only has the x64 version of the .NET framework. But my app requires x86 because of the 3rd party dlls. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Try compiling for Any CPU. Also make sure any previous versions are uninstalled before reinstalling. What architecture is the computer that has it successfully installed?

Comment: It's a windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: It used to be compiled for Any CPU. But I am using some 3rd party dll's that are 32 bit, so when the customer started deploying to x64 machines, it was not working because it was choosing the x64 version of the framework, and it was not compatible with the x86 3rd party dll's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sounds very plausible. I had the same exact problem. I needed to target x86 because of Access / Jet engine, which works only correct on x86, but on one taget Win7 machine, there was only the x64 Framework.

**Solution:** You will need to install the x86 .NET Framework on the target machine.